# Conditional statement in mixed integer linear programming

Tags: linear-programming, constraints, mixed-integer-programming

I have been trying to enforce the following conditional statement in a MILP:

If $X_1 + 2(X_2 + X_3) = 4$, then $X_4 = 1$.

where $X_1, X_2, X_3, X_4$ are binary.
How can I write this in conventional constraints, so that I could use a MILP solver?

Best regards,
Hans

Comment: Are $X_1, X_2, X_3, X_4$ integer variables or continuous variables?

Comment: they are binary!

Comment: It depends on the objective function and if it has to maximized or minimized. An isolated constraint alone makes it more complicated that it has to be. The constraints and the objective function are not independent from each other.

Comment: The objective function is a weighted sum of the 'X_i' 's and needs to be minimized, Something like '\sum_{i=1}^{27}' 'a_i' 'X_i' 's where 'a_i' 's are positive.

Answer (score 1):

If they are all binary, the only way $X_1 + 2 (X_2 + X_3) = 4$ is $X_1 = 0$, $X_2 = X_3 = 1$.  So your constraint could be $$-X_1 + X_2 + X_3 - X_4 \le 1$$

Answer (score 1):

As @RobertIsrael noted, your proposition is equivalent to
$$(\lnot X_1 \land X_2 \land X_3) \implies X_4.$$
Rewriting in conjunctive normal form yields
$$
\lnot (\lnot X_1 \land X_2 \land X_3) \lor X_4 \\
X_1 \lor \lnot X_2 \lor \lnot X_3 \lor X_4 \\
X_1 + (1 - X_2) + (1 - X_3) + X_4 \ge 1 \\
X_1 - X_2 - X_3 + X_4 \ge -1
$$